# Does ubuntu-make keep installed software up-to-date?

Tags: upgrade, tools, ubuntu-make

I have installed ubuntu-make from the official ppa and with it installed two IDEs and Unity3D. I am not clear on the upgrading process. Does ubuntu-make keep them up-to-date, do I need to do it from inside the IDE or should I use `umake` again?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to run umake again for them to update, it will download the latest copy and re-install overtop of the existing installation.